# Function: fromJSON Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using API to get some data from Flickr. I have downloaded packages: RJSONIO，RCurl and library them successfully.
This is what I tried:

> parsedData <- fromJSON(rawData)
>   Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

I am using Rstudio, and I have tried this method:
More->Set As Working Dictionary

> setwd("~/Desktop/Big data/1234")

What should I do next?

Comment: What's inside the `rawData` variable? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: inside the rawData is the getURL function.        
theURL <- paste0("the URL", 
                 "method=flickr.photos.search",
                 "&api_key=xxxxxx",
                 "&text=xxxxx", 
                 "&min_taken_date=2012-10-29 00:00:00", 
                 "&max_taken_date=2012-11-01 23:59:59", 
                 "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1")
theURL <- URLencode(theURL)
rawData <- getURL(theURL)
parsedData <- fromJSON(rawData)